# run a certain file (e.g. a .py) when a certain image, .wav or excel file get opened

Tags: linux, shell-script, files, monitoring

Recently, me and my friend have purchased a [Palm Vein Scanner](http://www.fulcrumbiometrics.com/Fujitsu-PalmSecure-Palm-Vein-Sensor-p/102400.htm). the goal was using it in a mini-project as a new door lock system. we are connecting it to a Raspberry Pi to run the software on it. raspberry pi runs Raspbian, a spin-off of Debian.

After receiving the Scanner, we realized that not any type of SDK or software libraries came with it, and buying the SDK or development bundle costs like 2.5K/7K$

However,the driver and a small demo file came with it. it's closed-source so we cannot add any modification to it. all we need is to add few lines of codes, so we send a small electrical signal to the door lock to open it. anyway, this seems to not be possible.

The demo file updates a small Excel spreadsheet every time someone uses the scanner. it adds a new raw that have the time, and whether the access has been granted or denied.

Can i use this in anyway possible? i was thinking of finding a way to run a .py file (that sends the signal to the door lock) every time the excel gets updated with ACCESS GRANTED.

or an easier way, a small .wav file gets loaded when access is granted! can i find a way to activate the .py file every time the .wav file gets played?

using bash scripts maybe?

Generally, in Linux,  how to make a certain file auto-execute when another audio file or image are opened or played?

Comment: I suppose you could watch the file that gets updated with ACCESS GRANTED with inotify or something, it depends on how it gets updated (rewritten in place vs. rewritten and renamed).